# How do I randomize the object I pull from the JSON Response in a GET Request

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

I'm very new to coding and working through a course on Javascript. As part of the Requests project, I needed to pull venue information using Foursquare's API. As it sits, it pulls from the array in order as it appears. I'm trying to randomize which venue it pulls. Here is my GET request block:

```
const getVenues = async () => {
  const city = $input.val();
  const urlToFetch = `${url}${city}&limit=10&client_id=${clientId}&client_secret=${clientSecret}&v=20210712`;

  try {
    const response = await fetch(urlToFetch);
    if(response.ok) {
      const jsonResponse = await response.json();
      const venues = jsonResponse.response.groups[0].items.map(item => item.venue);
      console.log(jsonResponse);
      return venues;
    };
  }
  catch(error) {console.log(error)};
};
```

My goal is to randomize the object from the array in the 'items' parameter. I've tried setting the venues variable to

```
const venues = Math.floor(Math.random(jsonResponse...)*10)
```

but this doesn't work. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a [Fisher-Yates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) shuffle to randomize array items.

I've used an implementation from [here](https://github.com/bubnicbf/Fisher-Yates-shuffle/blob/master/Fisher-Yates.js), thanks to the author [bubnicbf](https://github.com/bubnicbf)

We'll grab the items as normal, then pass our venues array to the FisherYatesShuffle function to randomize them.

```js
// https://github.com/bubnicbf/Fisher-Yates-shuffle/blob/master/Fisher-Yates.js
function FisherYatesShuffle(a) {
    var n = a.length,
        r,
        temp;
    while (n > 1) {
        r = Math.floor(n * Math.random());
        n -= 1;
        temp = a[n];
        a[n] = a[r];
        a[r] = temp;
    }
    return a;
}

// Assign values to allow function to run...
$input = { val() {} }
url = ''
city = ''
clientId = ''
clientSecret = ''

const getVenues = async () => {
  const city = $input.val();
  const urlToFetch = `${url}${city}&limit=10&client_id=${clientId}&client_secret=${clientSecret}&v=20210712`;

  try {
    const response = await fetch(urlToFetch);
    if(response.ok) {
      const jsonResponse = await response.json();
      const venues = jsonResponse.response.groups[0].items.map(item => item.venue);
      console.log('Venues (unshuffled):', venues);
      // Randomize our venues
      const shuffledVenues = FisherYatesShuffle(venues);
      console.log('Venues (shuffled):', shuffledVenues);
      return shuffledVenues;
    };
  }
  catch(error) {console.log(error)};
};

// Call the service
getVenues()

// Mocked version of fetch, for demonstration purposes.
function fetch() {
    const response = { 
        ok: true,
        json() { 
            return {
                response: { 
                    groups: [
                        { 
                            items: [
                               { venue: 'Venue 1'},
                               { venue: 'Venue 2'},
                               { venue: 'Venue 3'},
                               { venue: 'Venue 4'},
                               { venue: 'Venue 5'}
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return new Promise(resolve => { 
        setTimeout(resolve, 100, response)
    })
}
```

And a simpler demonstration is below, showing us shuffling our venues array:

```js
function FisherYatesShuffle(a) {
    var n = a.length,
        r,
        temp;
    while (n > 1) {
        r = Math.floor(n * Math.random());
        n -= 1;
        temp = a[n];
        a[n] = a[r];
        a[r] = temp;
    }
    return a;
}

const venues = [
    { venue: 'Venue 1'},
    { venue: 'Venue 2'},
    { venue: 'Venue 3'},
    { venue: 'Venue 4'},
    { venue: 'Venue 5'}
];
console.log("Venues:", venues);
console.log("Venues (shuffled):", FisherYatesShuffle(venues));
```

And last, but not least there is a lodash [shuffle](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#shuffle) function as well (that uses a version of Fisher-Yates)

```js
const venues = [
    { venue: 'Venue 1'},
    { venue: 'Venue 2'},
    { venue: 'Venue 3'},
    { venue: 'Venue 4'},
    { venue: 'Venue 5'}
];
console.log("Venues:", venues);
console.log("Venues (shuffled):", _.shuffle(venues))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.min.js" integrity="sha512-WFN04846sdKMIP5LKNphMaWzU7YpMyCU245etK3g/2ARYbPK9Ub18eG+ljU96qKRCWh+quCY7yefSmlkQw1ANQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```